# Gravity Form: Authentication via 3rd party API

Tags: php, wordpress

my situation:

- My wordpress website runs gravity form
- I've an existing web-app that offers our clients several functionalities via API

Login is performed on our web-app via POST on /session using username and password.

Is it possible to login on wordpress website authenticating via external API service ? (thus, exploiting the already existing user-db)